# Need to reverse a GIT commit

Tags: git

I've tried for hours to get back to the previous commit. Can anyone help me?
I pushed the master branch to my remote repo (the d34...commit), but it's the d6f (second down) commit I want.

When I try to change to that commit, I get this error: Are you sure you want to checkout 'd6fa4...[truncated]'?

Doing so will make your working copy a 'detached HEAD'

Can anyone please help me to remove that last commit from my develop and master branches?
Thank you!

More notes, because I have not explained this problem clearly:
When I checkout commit d6fa4... the codebase is exactly what I want. The merge commit (that I already pushed) brought together the master and develop branches.
If I check out d6fa4, I get a detached head, but again, the codebase is now correct. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to reset my master and develop branches to THAT commit.

I hope that makes it clearer. Thanks again!!

[image: SourceTree Screenshot]

Comment: Try `git reset --hard d34`, `git revert d34`.  Note that `reset --hard` will permanently discard any untracked changes.

Comment: Do you need to push the reverted change to a remote repository? Or just fix your local enlistment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seemed to have pushed the commit, you can do:

```
git revert d349d18
git push origin master
```

If you don't care about changing pushed history ( and especially if no one else is working on the repo), do:

```
git reset --hard d6fa474
```

( you can do that for both master and develop)

Comment: I can't 'revert' d34 because it was a merge commit. I get the error: "error: Commit d349d... is a merge but no -m option was given."

Comment: This solution actually worked for me. I had to add the -m 0. Thanks @manojids

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against deleting or reverting a pushed commit.
Create a new commit that reverts what you've done and push it. If you're working with other people, this can cause a lot of bad things on the repository.

Comment: You shouldn't delete (e.g., `reset --hard` over) a pushed commit. But `revert` is fine for pushed commits--they're the primary thing I use it for.

Comment: @EricWalker but if someone already pulled your commit ? then, it causes problems to that user

Comment: The revert commit undoes what was done in the reverted commit, but it does not rewrite history, so in the trivial case others will just fast forward when they pull.  If they've made changes, they'll have to merge, but they would have merge to for any other kinds of change as well, so the revert commit has not done anything particularly out of the normal.

Comment: Your right, however, doing revert will cause other people to do merge, instead of the person that actually made the revert, which is wrong, he did something bad, he should fix it.